# "Finite-Dimensional-Type-Spectral-Theorem" for Orthogonal Projections

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, not assumed separable, and $p$ and $q$ (bounded - not sure if that is important) orthogonal projections.

> **Question 1**: Is it the case that $p$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis for $H$/is diagonalisable?
>
> **Question 2**: Is it the case that $p$ and $q$ commute if and only if they share an eigenbasis/are simultaneously diagonalisable?

If the answer to question 1 is no, what are some reasonable assumptions on $H$ that guarantee such an eigenbasis exists (it seems to me that separability is enough. I don't think assumptions (such as compactness) on $p$ and $q$ are much good to me.).

If the answer to question 1 is no, do these assumptions give a positive answer to question 2?

Thanks for your help.

---

I am a little concerned when I work in infinite dimensions. For example I would just say, OK,
$$H=\operatorname{ran }p \oplus \ker{p},$$
each are closed and so each are Hilbert spaces and so each have onb... and just union those, bingo-bango, jobs a good 'un... but I am concerned there is an error there.

Comment: You are probably aware of this, but compact normal operator admit an orthonormal eigenbasis, so maybe that helps. In particular, compact projections have the property you want, but those are the projections on finite dimensional subspaces so not quite interesting.

Comment: Thank you, I think if $H$ is separable then everything works but I am wondering about non-separable. I might have to pass to a universal GNS at some stage which can fail to be separable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's nothing tricky about this.  As you say, $H$ is the orthogonal direct sum of the image of $p$ and the kernel of $p$.  Both of these are closed (the image is closed since it is the kernel of $1-p$), and so can pick orthonormal bases for each of them and their union is an orthonormal basis for $H$ which diagonalizes $p$.

If $p$ and $q$ commute, then $pq$, $p(1-q)$, $(1-p)q$, and $(1-p)(1-q)$ are all orthogonal projections which are pairwise orthogonal and their sum is $1$.  So again, $H$ is the orthogonal direct sum of their ranges, and picking an orthonormal basis for each of their ranges, you get an orthonormal basis for $H$ which simultaneously diagonalizes $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Nice one Eric. Always feel like I am on thin ice in infinite dimensions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in the second paragraph, how is the sum of those projections $1$?

Comment: Oops, I wrote the last one wrong.